# LESS.js - Can only import one .less file

Tags: css, less

I've been trying to split my less files up in to sections to make them easier to navigate, and want to import them all using one main file to compile them to css. my style.less file looks like this:

```
@import "reset";
@import "colors";
@import "grid";
@import "functions";
@import "headings";
@import "listings";
@import "content";
@import "buttons";
@import "layout";
@import "forms";
```

I'm using Winless to compile, and it says "Successfull Compile", but the resulting css file is completely blank. When I change my style.less file to only have one import, it imports that file no problem, so I know it's not a file directory/permissions problem. Any ideas? This is driving me mad. I love LESS, I don't want to have to do everything in one sheet.

I'm on a PC. Don't seem to have any trouble doing this at work on OSX, but I use Windows 7 at home and need something like Winless. I get the same results using less.js client side javascript file.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extensions, i.e. `@import "reset.less";`?

Comment: Yes. File extensions, using colons, speech marks and quotation marks, all the different methods on the site :/

Comment: I'd say you've got a bug to report to the Winless developers.

Comment: It also happens if I use the less.js file included to translate a less file client side though? I can't get it to import multiple files with WinLess, SimpLESS or LESS.js

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want to do this with LESS.js anyways. You'd be making 12 HTTP requests where a pre-compiled .css file would work.

Comment: are these files all in the same folder?

Comment: It's 2013 now, did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: As I was doing everything correctly and still use the same method, I have to assume this was a bug with WinLess. I've since moved on to SimpLESS and don't have any of the same problems. Not sure how to mark the question as 'solved'

Comment: I'm using an old version of WinLess 1.8.1 and Less 1.4.1 an that works perfectly, what version are u using???

Comment: This question is three years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was due to a bug in LESS.js, and has since been fixed. Additionally, I've now moved to SimpLESS on Windows, and CodeKit on OSX. Neither of these have the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue and it now works fine with less.js in v2.5.3.

```
@import "reset.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "color.less";
@import "custom.less";
```

CDN reference below:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script>
```

Just remember to put your:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/compiled.less"/>
```

before the less.js reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using less.js has given me issues. Like darylknight, I suggest an alternative. I present upon to thee [WinLess](http://winless.org/)